# Split text from Right to left based on the input passed

Tags: java

i have string and im trying to split the text and format it

Input is **67.9200 2 3**

Ouput will be **6 7.9 200**

Rules

```
1) split from the right to left based on the digits passed. 

2) when split contains "." then add 1 to it .

3) if anything is remaining will just show in the front.
```

Example
**67.9200 2 3**

```
 1. 3 (digits) -> will take the last 200
 2. 2 (digits) -> will take 7.9 (since it has ".")
 3. 6          -> Remaining will show (6)
```

Any suggestion or solutions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: *Any suggestion or solutions will be greatly appreciated* try writing some code.

Comment: can you share your code also ?

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat . i Completed that logic using StringUtils.mid(scaledValue.toString(),len-start,start) . im able to acheive the solution but im looking for better solution since i did using the for loop.

Comment: show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start scanning the string from right and keep storing them in a StringBuilder till you have captured n1(3) characters and whenever you encounter a dot, skip the count and once n1 becomes zero, append a space and move on. Apply same strategy for n2(2) and after you have the final string in StringBuilder, just reverse the string and you get your output. Here is a sample program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "67.9200";
    int n1 = 2;
    int n2 = 3;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (n2 > 0) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            sb.append(c);
            if (c != '.') {
                n2--;
                if (n2 == 0) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
        } else if (n1 > 0) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            sb.append(c);
            if (c != '.') {
                n1--;
                if (n1 == 0) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
}
```

This gives following output,

```
6 7.9 200
```

Comment: Thanks for response . why n1 is alone checking contains (".") it can come in any combination for example.  input "16.9200 1 2"  then output will be  "16.9 2 00". but ur regex producing different output

Comment: Changed my approach completely. Please check with this.

Comment: Thanks its works.. but is there anyway we can do this with Regex without loops . Any suggestions . Im trying to fix this with the regex